# "Normalize" procedure in C#

Tags: c#, normalization, geometry-surface

Could someone explain to me what the normalization procedure for 3D surface mesh in C# is?

In a reference book, there is a line as follows :

> The GetNormalize method is used to map
>   the region of your surface into a
>   region of [-1, 1], which gives you a
>   better view on your screen.

Answer (score 1):

You calculate the box bounding your surface mesh, get the longest side of the box and scale everything down by that value. The result will be [0,1] for that side and [0,<1] for the rest.

If you need [-1,1], you double everything and substract 1, getting [0,1]*2-1=[0,2]-1=[-1,1].